# Get function pointer from std::function that holds lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I want to get the raw function pointer from an `std::function` that has been assigned a lambda expression.

When `std::function` is assigned a regular function, this works as expected:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

bool my_function(int x) {}
using my_type = bool(*)(int);
int main() {
    std::function f = my_function;
    auto pointer = f.target<my_type>();

    // Prints 1
    std::cout << (pointer != nullptr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I change this example to use a lambda, it does not work:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using my_type = bool(*)(int);
int main() {
    std::function f = [](int) -> bool {};
    auto pointer = f.target<my_type>();

    // Prints 0
    std::cout << (pointer != nullptr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the second example print 0 and how could it be fixed to print 1?

Comment: what means "does not work"?

Comment: Sorry, clarified that it prints 0 instead of 1.

Comment: A lambda is not a function pointer. It sometimes can be converted to one, but you need to do it before you put it in `std::function`.

Comment: What do you want the function pointer _for_?

Comment: @PaulSanders I want to pass it as a callback to a C function.

Comment: If it's a non-capturing lambda, you don't need to use `std::function`.  Does that help?

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you for sharing your insights. Unfortunately my real code uses a capturing lambda, I wasn't aware that it makes a difference here.

Comment: Does your C function also take come kind of 'context' parameter (usually a `void *`)?

Comment: @PaulSanders It does actually :D You mean I could cast the lambda to `void*`?

Comment: Ok that approach seems to work for my use case (e.g. casting the lambda to void and then passing a generic wrapper function as the callback to C for unpacking the lambda from the void and calling into it. Thank you for this hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OP's comment that what he wants is something he can pass as a callback parameter to a C function, here is some quick proof-of-concept code that shows how to do that with a capturing lambda.  Please excuse the C-style casts but it's late and I'm tired.  `reinterpret_cast` should work just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void example_c_function (void (* callback) (void *context), void *context)
{
    callback (context);
}

int main ()
{
    int i = 42;
    std::function <void (void)> f = [=] { std::cout << i; };

    void (* callback) (void *) = +[] (void *context)
    {
        auto call_me = (std::function <void (void)> *) context;
        (*call_me) ();
    };

    example_c_function (callback, (void *) &f);
}
```

Output: 42 (yay!)

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KIvVlaBfUhhZcc0M)

Does that help, OP?

Answer (score 2):

Your trouble is the type of the lambda is NOT my_type.  It's an unspecified type.

Try this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto lambda = [](int x) -> bool { return x != 0; };
    std::function f = lambda;
    auto pointer = f.target<decltype(lambda)>();

    // Prints 1
    std::cout << (pointer != nullptr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This also seems to work with captures. Only downside is that it does not allow to pass the pointer to something that expects `my_type` (e.g. as a callback for a C function).